# get a disabled textbox value by clientid server side asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

----------------------EDIT

I guess in simpler terms what I am trying to do is get the post value of a disabled textbox to use in a SQL insert statement when the form is posted.

---

I need to get the value of a text box that is disabled with javascript. Ultimately I will use the value as a parameter of a SQL insert statement.  I have read that I need to get the value by doing something like this:

```
Request.Form(EnterDateTXT.ClientID)
```

my understanding is that this would only return the html rendered value of the control's ID.  how do I actually retrieve the value of the text in the textbox?

ASP.NET VB is the language I am working with

Comment: is ClientID the ID="ClientID" name of the textbox?The browser will use the control's name for posting the values back in POST. Look at form submission. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

Comment: Can you make textbox `readonly` instead of `disabled`?

Comment: Please consider marking an answer to this question, or add your own and mark it as the answer if you have solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Textboxvalue as string = textboox1.text

Comment: I should say that the text box is a asp.net textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

If your form requested by post method, You can get the value of form control by syntax

```
Request.Form(EnterDateTXT.ClientID)
```

in serverside.

you can refer the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.NET controls maintain their state on postbacks, there will be a `TextBox` object called EnterDateTXT available:

```
Dim txt as String = EnterDateTXT.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

What we do when retrieving the fields from the form, is execute the following recursive method. This takes care of readonly and disabled textboxes.

Because this method updates the textbox's Text property, no other code has to be concerned about the client-side state of the control:

```
''' <summary>
''' If a TextBox is marked as readonly, its value will not be updated into the server-side textbox control even though they are persisted.
''' This method copies the values from the Request.Form into textbox.text for all readonly textbox controls.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="cControls"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub RetrieveReadOnlyTextBoxValues(ByVal cControls As ControlCollection)
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    For Each oControl As Control In cControls
        If TypeOf oControl Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(oControl, TextBox).Text = Request.Form(oControl.UniqueID)
        End If
        If oControl.HasControls Then
            Call RetrieveReadOnlyTextBoxValues(oControl.Controls)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this sounds like what I need.  When I call `RetrieveReadOnlyTextBoxValues()` when I submit the form, what is the parameters I should pass for  `ByVal cControls As ControlCollection`

Comment: @mumis2012: Sorry, meant to include that: if this is in a page or a usercontrol, you pass `Me.Controls`. Also remember to only call it if not in a postback.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I was able to post the value of the textbox, while still not allowing the user to change the textbox's text, was to set the `readonly` attribute to `true` progamatically on `PageLoad`.  This way the textbox is "disabled" to user input, yet .NET4 will post the texbox's value set by the javascript.  I was able to access the textbox value as I usually would on the server side by accessing the .text property of the textbox.

my Understanding is that .NET preserves the state of the postback, and if the textbox is set to `enabled=false` or `readonly=true` then .NET assumes the values of these cantrols cannot be modified, and will not post the values.   by setting `enabled=false` or `readonly=true` on load, the postback state allows you to retrieve the text value

Comment: I experienced something similar; I was disabling a control using JQuery, and found then it wasn't posted to the server.  I don't know that it's .NET doing this, but may be the browser, as I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

A disabled control does not get posted back to the server necessarily.  I think that's the browser, and not the server doing that, but not 100% sure.  Anyway, if you hide it, or make it readonly, it should work fine.  Setting Enabled="false" on the server does not always mean disabled="disabled" on the client; sometimes, when you disable a control, it renders much differently.  It really depends on the control.